# Import using scopes in React Native using npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to change the way of importing modules in React Native. The standard method of doing that is something like this:

```
import HomeScreen from "../../screens/Home"
```

I sow that is also possible by doing:

```
import HomeScreen from "@screens/Home"
```

To do that, I tried to make a package.json file in screens folder and put it a name

```
{
   "name": "@screens"
}
```

but is not working.

**Update:**

I tried to use babel-plugin-module-resolver and configure it with my .babelrc and .tsconfig but the problem persists

***.babelrc***

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["./src"],
        "alias": {
          "test": "./test",
          "underscore": "lodash"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

***tsconfig.json***

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2017", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"],
      "test/*": ["test/*"],
      "underscore": ["lodash"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

PS: I am also using Typescript

Comment: what are you using to do your module loading?

Comment: I am using babel, with "react-native" preset

Comment: Then the .babelrc file is where you set up aliases. This article may be helpful to you: https://www.novis.co/post/custom-aliases-in-react-native-with-babel/

Comment: The `@` notation on the name of modules is used for [scope](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope).

Comment: https://github.com/iLeafSolutionsPvtLtd/react-native-boilerplate this is the project where I sow that they are using this symbol and it's very strange to me because .babelrc is standard

Comment: Why not simply do 'screens/Home' and "name": "screen" ? It work for me.

Comment: I did but without any success, I think that is because typescript is used

Comment: Update: I tried the babel-plugin-module-resolver and there is the same problem